# Parallelizing MapAt

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

What is the best way to parallelize `MapAt`? Only `ParallelMap` is provided, but seems bad when executing functions on a subset of a `List`. I only found 1 similar topic on SE where the subset was a whole level. (which it is not, in this case)

"minimal" working example:

I want to map the function f over `{All, All, 1}` of list l.

```
llength = 3
l = Table[ToString@a[x, y, z] Range@5, {x, llength}, {y, llength}, {z, llength}]
f[l_] := g /@ l


ParallelMap[Join[{f@#[[1]]}, #[[2 ;;]]] &, l, {2}] === MapAt[f, l, {All, All, 1}]
```

in this specific case a viable option might be using `Map` on level 2 and then using `ParallelMap` on element 1, mapping `f` to its elements. Is there a smarter way? This is not general for all index specifications.

Comment: I think the best method may be to first take `part = Part[l, All, All, 1]` and then use `newPart = ParallelMap[f, part]` to compute the values. You can use in-place modification: `l[[All, All, 1]] = newPart`. You can localize `l` if necessary.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit do you mind writing this as an answer? Otherwise i would take the burden upon me. Do you have a idea about performance/memory cost? This seems very redundant/inefficient in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (and simplest) thing having come to my mind is to `MapAt` tasks for parallel kernels and then to `WaitAll` them:

```
list = Array[h, {2, 3, 4}];
ClearAll[g];
g[x_] := (N[Pi, 10^6] x);
DistributeDefinitions[g];
WaitAll[
  MapAt[
   Composition[ParallelSubmit, g],
   list,
   {All, All, 1}
  ]
] === MapAt[g, list, {All, All, 1}]
(*True*)
```

Comment: as a function you could write it up like

SetAttributes[parallelMapAt, HoldAll];
parallelMapAt[fun_, list_List, spec__] := 
 Module[{}, DistributeDefinitions[fun]; 
  WaitAll[MapAt[Composition[ParallelSubmit, fun], list, spec]]]

correct?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick function that does mostly what you want:

```
parallelMapAt[
   fun_,
   list_List,
   spec__
 ] := Module[{
    copy = list
    },
   copy[[spec]] = ParallelMap[fun, copy[[spec]]];
   copy
  ];
```

However, the position specification follows the format of `Part` rather than that of `Position`:

```
In[400]:= parallelMapAt[Sin, N @ Range[20], {4, 6, 8, 10}] ===  
  MapAt[Sin, N @ Range[20], List /@ {4, 6, 8, 10}]
```

> Out[400]= True

Another example:

```
In[425]:= parallelMapAt[f, Array[# &, {5, 2}], All, 2]
```

> Out[425]= {{1, f[1]}, {2, f[2]}, {3, f[3]}, {4, f[4]}, {5, f[5]}}

If you're worried that making a copy of your input is inefficient (frankly, I doubt that it will give you much trouble), you can use `SetAttributes[parallelMapAt, HoldAll]` and modify the input list itself:

```
ClearAll[parallelMapAt]
SetAttributes[parallelMapAt, HoldAll]
parallelMapAt[
   fun_,
   list_Symbol?ListQ,
   spec__
   ] := (
   list[[spec]] = ParallelMap[fun, list[[spec]]]
 );

list = N @ Range[20];
parallelMapAt[Sin, list, {4, 6, 8, 10}]
list
```

> Out[420]= {-0.756802, -0.279415, 0.989358, -0.544021}
>
> Out[421]= {1., 2., 3., -0.756802, 5., -0.279415, 7., 0.989358, 9., \
>       -0.544021, 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.}

Of course, you may want to elaborate the code to do some error checking before you end up ruining your data by Part-assigning corrupt data if the `ParallelMap` fails.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, there is still some work to be done since

```
parallelMapAt[f, Array[h, {2, 3, 4}], All, All, 1] === MapAt[f, Array[h, {2, 3, 4}], {All, All, 1}]
```

is `False`. In this case, you'd need to add the levelspec `{2}` to `ParallelMap` to make it work correctly. I suspect that the level spec should be equal to the number of non-flattened levels (e.g., `All` or `;; 3`) in `spec`, but I can't test that right now.

Comment: `parallelMapAt[f, Array[h, {2, 3, 4}], All, All, 1] === 
 MapAt[f, Array[h, {2, 3, 4}], {All, All, 1}]` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @Anton.Sakovich Hmmm, yes. I see why. You have to give `ParallelMap` the right levelspec for this to work. Right now I don't have the time to figure out how to deduce the right levelspec programmatically.